# Notification authorization after backup iPhone

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm an iOS developer and I'm facing an issue because of notification device token.

I have an application that allows notifications and it works well except for one case when I authorize notifications, save a backup of the first phone, and restore the backup in a second phone. When I launch my application in the second phone I don't have the pop-up window to authorized the push notifications and get the device token in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.

Sorry for my English and thank you in advance.

Comment: you do get the device token or you dont :)

Comment: i don't because the pop-up doesn't show so i think didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken doesn't fire also, i think that the system doesn't consider that it's the first launch of the app

Comment: and also because some users sends us emails and they told that after doing a backup they don't receive notifications , so i did a test :
1 - I downloaded the app from the store and i launch it and authorize notifications.
2 - i did i save in itunes.
3 - i take another iphone and i did a rollback with the other save.
4 - when i launched the app it didn't show me the pop-up window to authorized the push notifications

Comment: so i don't know what i can do to get the device token for the second iphone

Comment: you register the UserSettings ok? the dialog shouldn't matter... this method is called ever time. Implement the didFail method to debug more!?